# Can't create a LookUpField

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

I am creating a new list and trying to add a LookUp field on the list.

I retrieve the list I want to look up against:

```
let list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trucks");
    list.get().then(list => {
        this._ensureMyList("MySPListTest", list)
    });
```

I then create the new list and the new field:

```
private _ensureMyList(listName: string, truckList): void {
    sp.web.lists.ensure(listName)
        .then((ler: ListEnsureResult) => {
            if (ler.created) {
                console.log("list was created");

                ler.list.fields.add("LookupTest", "SP.FieldLookup", { 
                    Group: "~Example",
                    FieldTypeKind: 7,
                    Filterable: true,
                    Hidden: false,
                    EnforceUniqueValues: true,
                })
                    .then((result) => {
                        console.log("result: ", result);
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [500]  ::> {"responseBody":{"odata.error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Please use addfield to add a lookup field instead."}}},"responseHeaders":{}}
```

I got the Field name and TypeKind from:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldLookup

I also tried using the `addLookup` method:

```
ler.list.fields.addLookup("LookupTest", truckList.Id, "Truck")
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("result: ", result);
    });
```

With error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400]  ::> {"responseBody":{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method AddField."}}},"responseHeaders":{}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the following options to add lookup field:

1) via [`Fields.addLookup` method](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/606f55fc8468049cf7a21a49756f83aa0badaabc/src/sharepoint/fields.ts#L319):

```
let list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle);  //get list resource
let lookupList = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(lookupListTitle).select("Id").get();  //select Lookup List Id 
let field = await list.fields.addLookup(lookupFieldName, lookupList.Id ,"Title"); // add lookup field to list
```

2) via `Fields.createFieldAsXml` method:

```
let list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle); //get target list resource
let lookupList = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Categories").select("Id").get(); //determine lookup list id
let fieldXml = `<Field Name="Category" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Category" List="{${lookupList.Id}}" ShowField="Title"/>`;  //construct lookup field schema
let field = await list.fields.createFieldAsXml(fieldXml);  //add field to list
```

**References**

[PnPjs Add Fields](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/fields/#add-fields)

**Update**

Regarding the error which occurs while invoking `Fields.addLookup` method:

> the parameter __metadata does not exist in method AddField.

it seems there is a bug with in the latest version (`v1.2.1`) for  [`Fields.addLookup` method](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/5e535d3ce265ad1dede6d53de3ddd594c04d42a1/packages/sp/src/fields.ts#L307). The point is it generates *invalid* payload, something like this:

```
{
   "__metadata":{
     "type":"SP.FieldCreationInformation"
   },
   "parameters": { 
          "FieldTypeKind":7,
          "LookupFieldName":"Title",
          "LookupListId":"{list-id}",
          "Title":"Cat"
   }
}
```

`parameters` should be the **root** tag in payload for `http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'<list id>')/fields('<field id>')/addfield` endpoint ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldLookup))

[According to the history](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/commit/1fb0a553db877667682ea335740e898a3565ba1e#diff-9adb7427d394038990be033d080ed24f) this bug has been introduced with one of the later commit, anyway it's better to report an issue.

Comment: Option 1 is giving me the same errors in my post. Option 2 is awesome and is working, thank you!  Any idea why I keep getting those errors?

Comment: @Holden1515, indeed it occurs, the answer has been updated

Comment: Ah!  Thank you for the digging and submitting the report!